# Pandas Dataframe groupby: produce multiple output columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following code:

```
def func(x):
  return (1, 2, 3)

df.groupby[col].aggregate(func)
```

How to make three columns as the result of one aggregation function? I also tried returning np.array, pd.Series, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Can you please share sample input and expected output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `func()` you have to return a dataframe and I believe you should use `apply()`, for example like so:

```
def func(x):
    return pd.DataFrame([1,2,3]).T

df.groupby[col].apply(func)
```